# MPEG-4/WAV container for quick A/V sync tweaking

Tags: video, video-processing, codec, video-codecs, mpeg-4

Which container formats support an MPEG-4 video with a WAV audio stream? I'm
looking for a format which is supported by most players.

Is there a such format which would allow to adjust the A/V sync offset very
quickly, by modifying a field in the header, without the need to copy or
transcode the whole file?

Comment: For information, I have started a thread on ffmpeg-user about this: http://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2011-April/000399.html